# Centering Labels Above Inputs using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center my labels on top of me datetimepicker inputs but `text-align:center` does not seem to be cutting it.

http://jsfiddle.net/aesh3ufk/4/

Does anyone know how to center the labels on top of my inputs? Even !important does not work...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4><strong>ITEMS CHECKED IN</strong></h4>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
            <label for="From">From</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' id="From" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
            <label for="To">To</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' id="To" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an easy fix actually. Just add `text-center` to your `col-md-6` `<div>`s:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4 class="CAlign"><strong>ITEMS CHECKED IN</strong></h4>
        <!-- Right Here -->
        <div class='col-md-6 text-center'>
            <label for="From">From</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' id="From" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- And Here -->
        <div class='col-md-6 text-center'>
            <label for="To">To</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' id="To" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aesh3ufk/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The label's `display` style is `inline-block` and you must change it to `block` in order to be able to align the text to the center

Answer (score 1):

One option is just to add the `.text-center` [Bootstrap class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) to the parent div like so:

```
         <div class='col-md-6 text-center'>
            <label for="From">From</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' id="From" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aesh3ufk/6/